# Text message show alert

Tags: android

How an alert dialog can be open when accessing the text message in android? I am running a service in the background, when ever user access the text message some alert I need to show? How this can be achieved? Please help me...

Comment: any event at that time like toast or dialog or any activity etc.

Comment: So what is the problem you are getting to show the simple Toast....?

Comment: How to find the user is open the text message?

Comment: Not able to get you exactly what you are trying to do man...

Comment: I will run a service, in that service i need to check the condition like, if user touch or click the text message an alert or toast have to be shown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4059/discussion-between-lalit-poptani-and-thiru)

Comment: I think he wants something like this : He wants to show a notification(Toast or Alert) when user reads(he said access) a message from default android messaging application ? Am i correct ?

Comment: @Kartik I think he is saying that when user touches  or click at that time he wants to show a Toast or Dialog...Its confusion actually...

Comment: @Karthik - Yes. But here if user opens the default text message app, it have to toast or alert.

Comment: @Sherif - y? can you give some other way to proceed with it?

Comment: You might be able to catch if the user sent a message, but to catch that he started the messaging application you'd better forget it. You could add in your application "link to the sms application". In this way, you can know when he presses it.

Comment: Hi Thiru., in which chat room u r?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I m @ android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible. Can able listen only on incoming or outgoing text message. Thanks for your support friends.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you show text message? In the activity?

If yes, then in the method onResume() show dialog.

Or try to ask more explicit question, telepaths are on the vacation.